# how can i drag and drop the some information from one window to another window?

Tags: windows

how can i drag and drop the some information from one window to another window?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave more context, like what programming language, what the data is, are these your windows or other programs, are you even writing a program or are you just a lost user, etc...

Comment: Also, what is the "window" we're talking about? Is it a web page (two browser windows?), a desktop application (what OS?), what?

Answer (score 1):

I always like [SHDoDragDrop()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762151(VS.85).aspx).